# wso 2 3.0.0 alters not getting in admin portal for non admin users

Tags: wso2

I have done configuration like analytics worker - allINone wso2 3.0.0 and analytics dashboard

1. enabled alerts in analytics worker
2. through publisher setup alerts for response time and backend response time
3. logged in as admin user on devportal and tested API
4. logged in through the admin portal() and I can see alters for response time threshold
5. logged in to devportal as another user(non-admin)(but has all the roles) tested the API
6. logged in through the admin portal() and I **cant** see alters for response time threshold

response time threshold I have set as 1 milisec

Error in worker
[2020-09-11 11:22:59,710] ERROR {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SslHandshakeCompletionHandlerForServer} - Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Comment: what is your question, how can someone help you?

Comment: @Nessi question is why alerts generated by calling api by non-admin users are not visible in admin portal(https://localhost:9443/admin/analytics-alerts)